# I modified the iOS app, but when I build and run it with xcode 4, it doesn't change

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I made an app (already approved in the app store) with xcode 4 and it runs.

Now I would like to modify it for an update. My app has 2 localize (English and Italian) and before I modified it, I removed the second localize. My app is a tab bar app with 3 buttons.

My problem is that I added a new button to the tab bar in the mainWindow (everything is correct also name and nib) but it doesn't appear when I run it on my iphone nor on the simulator (iphone or ipad 3.2, 4.0 or 4.2). It works only on the 4.3 simulator (my iphone is 4.3.3).

If I remove the mainWindow (both), then it works on the iphone and 3.2, 4.0, 4.3 simulator as before I modified it.

What can i do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, try a full clean and rebuild.  I've found xCode likes to hold onto old files if they're (mistakenly) marked as unmodified, doing a full clean and rebuild usually fixes this problem

Answer (score 1):

Like @Dan F says, clean and rebuild is a must. Also I've found that putting out releases won't work unless you increase the app version number. If it's currently at 1.0 try changing it to 1.1 (or however you want to version your app) and see if that fixes it.

Otherwise you'll want to play around with your build settings and make sure the versions you're building for are correct. Just a few thoughts...